# How print wireless (wifi) adapter driver name in bash?

Tags: bash, wifi, driver, linux-device-driver

I didn't find this question here, so I came up with my own solution:

```
lshw -c network | grep wireless | grep driver | gawk -F' ' '{ while(++i<=NF){ if($i ~ /driver\=/){ sub("driver=","",$i); print $i; } } }';
```

I needed this in purpouse of restart wifi module without knowing it's name like:

```
WIFI_DRIVER=$(lshw -c network | grep wireless | grep driver | gawk -F' ' '{ while(++i<=NF){ if($i ~ /driver\=/){ sub("driver=","",$i); print $i; } } }');

sudo modprobe -r $WIFI_DRIVER && sudo modprobe $WIFI_DRIVER
```

Any better and more reliable solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it more efficient by getting rid of the greps and adding these two rules to the beginning of your awk script:

```
!/wireless/ { next }
!/driver/   { next }
```

Also, you don't need to specify a single space as the field separator since that's the default.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is `perl -lne '/wireless/ && /driver=(.*?)\s/ && print $1'`:

Ex:

```
sudo lshw -c network  | perl -lne '/wireless/ && /driver=(.*?)\s/ && print $1'
iwlwifi
```